# Syntax error when I try to use bash from sh `echo 'rm -rf !(cookbooks)' | bash`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, packer

When I use /bin/sh I can issue commands through bash simply by echoing to it

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sh
$ echo 'ls' | bash
some.sh
```

But when I try to use this command `rm -rf !(cookbooks)` I get this

```
$ echo 'rm -rf !(cookbooks)' | bash
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: line 1: `rm -rf !(cookbooks)'
```

And I need issue this command from /bin/sh.

@anubhava from a packer http://www.packer.io/ provision script

```
if [ -d "/opt/chef/chef-solo/" ]; then
  cd /opt/chef/chef-solo
  rm -rf !(cookbooks)
fi
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: ...actually, I realized (quite belatedly) that the easy solution is just to use find, and not rely on bashisms *or* POSIX sh contortions at all.

Comment: Since the `--delete` option is a GNU extension to `find`, using it would be comparable to a bashism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!(cookbooks)` is an extglob. They're not enabled by default; you need to run `shopt -s extglob` in a prior line of bash (because the parser operates line-by-line) to make it valid.

So:

```
printf '%s\n' 'shopt -s extglob' 'rm -rf !(cookbooks)' | bash
```

...or you can enable extglobs via the command line (thanks to [chepner](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for the addendum):

```
echo 'rm -rf !(cookbooks)' | bash -O extglob
```

By the way, it *is* possible to do this in POSIX sh, without use of extglobs. For instance:

```
# wrap in a function to have a separate $@ rather than overriding global
delete_all_but_cookbooks() {
  set --
  for f in *; do
    [ "$f" = "cookbooks" ] || set -- "$@" "$f"
  done
  rm -rf "$@"
}
delete_all_but_cookbooks
```

...or, much simpler, just using find:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name cookbooks -prune -o -exec rm -rf '{}' +
```

Comment: You can enable `extglob` when you start `bash` with `bash -O extglob`.

Comment: And GNU find has --delete action built-in

Comment: I'll add that shopt -s extglob needs to run before the current context, not just the current line.  I had a case where my need for extglob was inside an 'if' and so shopt -s extglob had to be run outside the 'if'.  Placing it above the needed line was not enough (received the same error "...unexpected token `('".